# How to create a limited user account for SSH

Tags: ssh, files, users

I need to create a new user account, that should have full access to a single dir within the linux HDD, unlike the root user that has access to everything. And this account would be used via SSH for file sharing on the network. How do I get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a normal user, and set it's home dir to the desired folder:

```
useradd -d /share username
```

If you explicitly do not add this user to sudoer's list, or any special groups, then it will be limited by default. For security purposes you might want even to `chroot` that user.

Comment: By default users can read quite a lot of files on Ubuntu systems. When I create a new user, everyone has read-only access the home directory by default. So without a ``chroot`` configuration it's definitely not secure at all in my opinion. See my answer on how to do that.

Comment: Is it possible to create a read only session where the user is not allowed to type but only to view the typing.

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey, please explain, I don't really understand your question.

Answer (score 3):

File transfer (and sharing) over SSH is done using the `sftp` protocol usually.

And you can set up OpenSSH to `chroot` to the user's directory while forcing `sftp` (no command line allowed) like explained in [this how-to](http://shapeshed.com/chroot_sftp_users_on_ubuntu_intrepid/).